# ANTLRv3: Setting a custom Lexer and Parser Class names

Tags: antlr, antlr3, context-free-grammar

Is there a way to specify custom class name (meaning independent of the grammar name) for the ANTLRv3 generated Parser and Lexer classes?

So in the case of

```
grammar MDD;

//other stufff
```

Automatically it would crate MDDParser and MDDLexer, but I would like to have them as MDDBaseParser and MDDLexer.

Answer (score 1):

No, in a combined grammar like `MDD`, the parser and lexer are named MDDParser and MDDLexer. A combined grammar is a grammar where you don't specify the type (`parser` or `lexer`).

You could define a separate parser- and lexer-grammar:

```
// put this in a file called MDDBaseParser.g
parser grammar MDDBaseParser;

parse
  :  Token+
  ;
```

and:

```
// put this in a file called MDDLexer.g
lexer grammar MDDLexer;

Token
  :  'a'..'z'
  ;
```

Now both the parser and lexer source files will get the same name as their grammar file.